# XSLT transformation (XML to CSV)

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am new to xslt programming and would like your help in the below.

I have to generate a CSV report from XML baring the following appearance. (I am not sure if running totals is possible)

Output Expected:

```
Sum Insured Report

UK
Sl.No.  Policy #        Customer #      Cover Note #    No. of Addendas     Sum Insured     GP(SumCustDeb - SumCustCred)        NP(SumInsCred - SumInsDeb)      Total Commission
1       414227          3321            50242           2                   21000           1700                                1700                            850
2                       ABC             12345           0                    2000            500                                 500                             10
3       1A2B            XYZ             98765           1                   60000            100                                 100                             60
                                                                    Total:  83000           2300                                2300                            920
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="true"?><Message MessageId="1-OC05" IntObjectName="Report IO" MessageType="Integration Object" IntObjectFormat="Hierarchical">
    <ReportIo>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda>50242-1</Addenda>
         <CommAmt>700</CommAmt>
         <Cover>50242</Cover>
         <Customer>3321</Customer>
         <Policy>414227</Policy>
         <SumCustCred>500</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>1000</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>1000</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>500</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda>50242-2</Addenda>
         <CommAmt>50</CommAmt>
         <Cover>50242</Cover>
         <Customer>3321</Customer>
         <Policy>414227</Policy>
         <SumCustCred>0</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>500</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>500</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>0</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>1000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda></Addenda>
         <CommAmt>100</CommAmt>
         <Cover>50242</Cover>
         <Customer>3321</Customer>
         <Policy>414227</Policy>
         <SumCustCred>0</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>700</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>700</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>0</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda></Addenda>
         <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
         <Cover>12345</Cover>
         <Customer>ABC</Customer>
         <Policy></Policy>
         <SumCustCred>0</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>500</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>500</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>0</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>2000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda></Addenda>
         <CommAmt>50</CommAmt>
         <Cover>98765</Cover>
         <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
         <Policy>1A2B</Policy>
         <SumCustCred>0</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>0</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>0</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>0</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>10000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
        <Policies>
         <Addenda>98765-1</Addenda>
         <CommAmt>10</CommAmt>
         <Cover>98765</Cover>
         <Customer>XYZ</Customer>
         <Policy>1A2B</Policy>
         <SumCustCred>0</SumCustCred>
         <SumCustDeb>100</SumCustDeb>
         <SumInsCred>100</SumInsCred>
         <SumInsDeb>0</SumInsDeb>
         <SumInsured>50000</SumInsured>
         <Organization>UK</Organization>
        </Policies>
    </ReportIo>
</SiebelMessage>
```

XSLT Used, But I am stuck in the very first step while trying to display Organization as 'UK'. Systems says "XSLT Processing Exception: XSLT error: xsl:value-of is not allowed at this position in the stylesheet"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://www.canto.com/ns/Export/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/ReportIo">
<xsl:text>Sum Insured Report</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>SNo.</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Policy #</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Customer #</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Cover Note #</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>No. of Addendas</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Sum Insured</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>GP</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>NP</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Total Commission</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each-group select="Policies" group-by="Organization"> <!--Group by Organization-->
<xsl:value-of select="Organization"/> <!--Display the Organization-->
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Cover">
<xsl:for-each-group select="position()"/> <!--Trying to generate Sequence Number-->
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Policy"/>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Customer"/>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="Cover"/>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(current-group()/Addendas))"/> <!-- Getting Distinct Count of Addendas while it is not blank-->
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/SumInsured)"/> <!-- Summation of SumInsured element within the 'Cover' group-->
<!-- Not sure how to get GP & NP, if it is at all possible>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="GP"/>
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="NP"/>
<End of GP & NP-->
<xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/CommAmt)"/>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Following tag also is providing incorrect values as blank Addenda's are being considered:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(current-group()/Addendas))"/>
```

Here I am unable to get the sum:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/SumInsured)"/>
```

Please excuse the size of the request. Any help will be taken gladly.

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(current-group()/Addendas))">` end tag is not there for this xsl:value-of can you check adding that ?

Comment: thats a typo...added the same into the xsl above. however I am unsure how to check for blank tags, as currently it gives me value '3' where as it should be '2'

Comment: ok that wasnt clear in the question that you want to check for blank tags, i thought the issue is related to `xsl:value-of` can you update the question unless my understanding is wrong

Comment: yes error while generating the report points to be first xsl:value-of tag, when i tried to apply line by line, the other issues were seen. Updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this line from your stylesheet (line #31):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="position()"/> <!--Trying to generate Sequence Number-->
```

---

Note also that your `<xsl:template match="/ReportIo">` assumes that `ReportIo` is the root element - but the input you show us has a `<Message>` opening tag and a `</SiebelMessage>` closing tag, making it ill-formed XML.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your response, I have removed it yet the same issue is seen, pointing to line <xsl:value-of select="Policy"/>

Comment: Give me a moment please, I am not familiar with the tool/link shared by you. (Need to do some tinkering) I will try again with live data in my system.

Comment: @AnnaJoel Please tell us what XSLT processor you are using (the "system" you have mentioned). Also, make sure that in your question above, you show exactly the XSLT code and XML input you feed into your own system.

Comment: @Mathias I am using an Inbuilt Business Service Called "EAI XSLT Service" in Siebel System. I am aware that it supports XSLT 2.0..The XSLT code & XML shown in my question are the same applied just with shortened names & data

Comment: Could you please have a look at "http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpL/1" i have pasted the exact xml and xsl used in my system, but am not sure how to run the transformation

Comment: @AnnaJoel The transformation runs automatically. The result you see is produced by the built-in template rules, because your template does not match anything: `ListOfAceClientSumInsuredReportIo` is **not** the root element. See what happens when you fix that: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpL/5

Comment: Thank u thank u thank u so much, i will add the other tags and get back

Comment: Is there a way I can add sequence Number? Also I want the No. of Addendas to display 2, where the null value is not considered. Is it possible to have totals for the Numeric data? + Is there a better way to code my xsl without the repeating "tab" and "line break" tags?....sorry for the million questions. I am really grateful for all your help. This is the last change applied: [link](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpL/8)

Comment: @AnnaJoel Which XML should we consider as your input? So far I have only hunted for errors, I did not look at your actual code.

Comment: The one shared @ [Link](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpL/8), being my actual live data...

Comment: @Michael My application uses  Xalan 1.5 engine for transformation and when I changed to the same in the XML Transformation tool, I encountered many errors. Could you please advise me how to go about

Comment: @AnnaJoel Xalan is a strictly XSLT 1.0 engine, so you won't be able to use any XSLT 2.0 features - starting with `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: ok. I shall raise another question for this then. I have managed to get the top level grouping for Organization using XSLT 1.0 but am unaware how to apply the next level group within group concept. Thank u once again for your patience, time & efforts